# How do you represent inheritance in LinqToSql?

Tags: linq-to-sql, inheritance

I need to represent inheritance like Person/Student. How do you do that in LInqToSql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try : [linqtosql inheritance](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/01/linq-to-sql-inheritance.aspx) or [another linqtosql inheritance](http://tinyurl.com/6benub)